# Logstash - Change Alphabetic Month to Numeric

Tags: regex, logstash, grok

I have been trying to develop the Regex to convert alphabetic month (ex. Sep) to numeric equivalent (09)

Comment: Not really a regex work, more of a text substitution one. Or another built-in way to do it with your tools

Answer (score 0):

The translate{} filter would work well for this.

Answer (score 0):

using the `date`filter with the `MMM`pattern will work fine for that:

```
filter {
  date {
    match => [ "yourfield", "MMM" ]
  }
}
```

Available Regexes can be found on the [DateTimeFormat](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) documentation.